# ILNumerics - 3d plots

Tags: plot, 3d, ilnumerics

Is there any existing functionality or planned functionality for 3d (xyz) data conversion into a regular grid? I looked into the documentation and code and could not find the necessary methods. In MATLAB the corresponding method is:

```
griddata(dataX, dataY, dataZ, gridXTicks, gridYTicks, rouding_method)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such single function in ILNumerics. However, the lib makes it easy to implement it yourself. You may want to take a look at ILMath.pinv() or ILMath.ridge_regression(). A similar question has been asked on the old ILNumerics [forum](http://ilnumerics.net/forum/index.php?p=/discussion/252/clarification-of-arguments-to-ridge_regression...). It uses the old visualization API (prior to version 3). But the math is still the same. If I find the time, I'll post an example.